# Ionic 3 with sql database connection

Tags: php, ionic-framework, ionic3

hey guys i need to connect my ionic app with mysql database but could'nt do that. i have created config.php in my xamp htdocs. 
here is config.php

```
<?php
//ob_start("ob_gzhandler");
error_reporting(0);
session_start();
/* DATABASE CONFIGURATION */
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'upload');
define("BASE_URL", "http://localhost/ionic/api/");
define("SITE_KEY", 'yourSecretKey');
function getDB() 
{
    $dbhost=DB_SERVER;
    $dbuser=DB_USERNAME;
    $dbpass=DB_PASSWORD;
    $dbname=DB_DATABASE;
    $dbConnection = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, 
$dbpass);   
    $dbConnection->exec("set names utf8");
    $dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    return $dbConnection;
}
/* DATABASE CONFIGURATION END */
/* API key encryption */
function apiToken($session_uid)
{
$key=md5(SITE_KEY.$session_uid);
return hash('fahad123', $key);
}
?>
```

now anyone here can help me with this to connect my ionic 3 app with this database mysql listed above.

Comment: Have you read the documentation about ionic? Do you get some error when you try to connect the db?

Comment: i just coded config.php. i need a basic connection with mysql that prints name that is inserted there already.

Comment: @Sfili_81 kindly provide me a source code or help me with that to make a connection with mysql

Comment: Copy and paste isnt some kind of effort. Try more, read tutorials, when you reach some error/issue, then ask.

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect your Mobile App through an RESTful / GraphQL API. First, learn how to create API endpoints with PHP for example and use Ionic App's providers to deal with your API. There are other alternatives like the Ionic Platform, Firebase. 
Hope I help! 
[image: Architecture overview]